# Unable to get emoji properly in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, emoji, toolkit

I am trying for binding the emoji to the rich textbox with an extended tool kit. I am able to do it but the emoji is displaying differently for the text box. I am getting it ass follows:

[image]

I am binding the value as following:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(ApplicationContext.Emojis[emote].ToString(),
                                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                            BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();

                            source.BeginInit();
                            source.UriSource = uri;
                            source.DecodePixelHeight = 25;
                            source.DecodePixelWidth = 25;

                            source.EndInit();


                            if (IsNullOrEmpty(MessageText.Text))
                                _contactsViewModel.TypedMessage = " ";
                            else if (!dataObjectToSend.Contains(MessageText.Text?.Trim('\r', '\n')))
                                dataObjectToSend.Add(MessageText.Text);

                            dataObject.SetImage(source);

                            dataObjectToSend.Add(selectedBindingContext.text.ToString());
                            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);

                            TextPointer caretPos = MessageText.CaretPosition;

                            caretPos = caretPos.DocumentEnd;
                            MessageText.CaretPosition = caretPos;
                            MessageText.Paste();
```

and my Textbox is

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding TypedMessage,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                     x:Name="MessageText"  
                                                     Grid.Column="1" 
                                                     BorderThickness="0" 
                                                     BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                                                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                                                     Foreground="Black"
                                                     FontSize="16"
                                                     Margin="0,2,2,2"
                                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                     KeyUp="OnTypingMessage" 
                                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                                     LostFocus="MessageText_OnLostFocus"
                                                     SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true">
```

What I want is to display the emoji in richTextBox as

[image]

Can some help me to achieve this, please.

Comment: check this https://github.com/samhocevar/emoji.wpf

Comment: Thanks for link @Aybe , I've tried using this but the emoji: RichTextBox is very slow at rendering. Only one emoji is visible if we select multiple emojis they are not visible within the emoji: RichTextBox.